# rails, gem, and other commands not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Many commands are not able to be executed in the terminal.

From looking around, the likely reason is that the $PATH is not pointing to the right place, but the solutions offered would not change anything on my machine, i.e. my $PATH is set up correctly

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/usr/.rvm/bin:/home/usr/.rvm/bin` (the one is repeated, i don't know why)

I am in the directory ruby is installed in when trying to execute the commands.
Anything else that would help you pinpoint the problem, let me know

Comment: We need a lot more information. WHAT directory is Ruby installed in? How did you install Ruby?

Comment: You say your `PATH` is correct but either that's not the case, or your Ruby components are installed somewhere other than you expect. `find / -name rails` or `which rails` can help find it.

Comment: How did you install ruby? Where do you expect the executable to be? Don't naively assume that your `$PATH` is correct; it clearly isn't, since the `ruby` executable cannot be found! For example, if you installed ruby via RVM then `/home/<your-username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-<VERSION>/bin` would also need to be in your `$PATH`.

Comment: please specify version

Comment: `/home/<your-username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-<VERSION>/bin` is not in `$PATH`, so I'll guess this is an issue.

Ruby version 2.3.3 installed with rvm version 1.28. Ruby is installed in my `workspace` directory. 

running the find function returns a bunch of permission denieds